# How to get directory path up to a specific folder only?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Using: CF10 and IIS7.5

I have a section within my website called "Bookings". It is located like this:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings
```

Within this folder will be sub-folders and eventually webpages themselves. Heres an example:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings\holidays\new.cfm
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings\carhire\edit.cfm
```

I include (using `<cfinclude>`) another page within each webpage that displays different links depending on which page is calling it. All I want to know is the directory up to the "bookings" folder. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
<cfset whereAmI = #GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())#>
 <cfif #whereAmI# EQ "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings">
 <h1>Booking Section Links</h1>
 </cfif>
```

The above code works only if the user visits the `bookings/index.cfm` page of the "bookings" folder. But if they go to the `bookings/holidays/new.cfm` page, it is now in the `holidays` folder so the `<h1>` content will not appear. I really only want to check for any page that is in the bookings folder, even if it is within a subfolder within the bookings folder. A bit like in SQL where I could say `IF #GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())# LIKE 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings%'` so it has a wildcard on the end.

I know this question is going to irritate the MVC framework advocates but please excuse me on this!

Comment: If your paths are consistent you can treat as strings and do `CurrentDir.startsWith(RootDir)` - but that wont work if you've got a mix of slashes or SUBST drives or other things.

Comment: Peter's approach is one way to do it, but another is to compare the left 34 characters of `whereAmI` vs your folder `<cfif left(whereAmI,34) EQ "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings">`

Comment: @PeterBoughton I will have other sections such as `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\accounts\staff\index.cfm` so in this case I'm again looking for parent directory of "accounts".

Comment: Yes, and? Call the variable `SectionRootDir` or do `RootDir & 'accounts\'` or whatever. Letting the computer work it out is definitely preferable to having hardcoded human-counted numbers.

Comment: I would not write this based on absolute (or relative) paths as they could change, making your script useless. One way to handle this would be to set a variable in the included files that you then use that to determine what needs to be displayed.

Comment: @PeterBoughton would you mind posting your suggestion as an answer so I can see how to do it with my example code?

Comment: Hrm...re-reading your post, it is possible that the `cfinclude` may be happening after you actually need to know where you are so that you can display the links. If that is the case, you could set some a variable in the logic that determines which file to `cfinclude` and then use that variable to determine what links to be displayed. And, sorry, I cannot resist...this problem could easily be solved had you chosen to use a framework. :D

Comment: @ScottStroz the <cfinclude> file has all the logic in it that so that it knows which page is "calling" it and what to display. A bit like `<cfif whereAmI EQ "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings\new.cfm"><h1>Display some content specific to new bookings here</h1>
<cfif>`

Comment: I see that now. Check out my posted answer. It should get you what you need for now, and possibly give you a path to go down should you need something more robust in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick, easy way to solve your problem (may not work as system expands - but should get you started down the right path).

```
<cfset whereAmI = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())>
<cfif whereAmI CONTAINS "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bookings">
   <h1>Booking Section Links</h1>
</cfif>
```

Note, I removed the `#` from inside the `cfset` and `cfif`  you do not need them there.

You could even scale back the path to use just 'mysite\bookings'.

Ideally, this should be wrapped up into a function so that you can easily pass different paths into it to determine if you are on a given page. Or, possibly, even determine the 'parent' folder in `onRequestStart` in Application.cfc and set it as a request scope variable.

This will need to be tweaked if you run the code on a *nix based system.

Comment: wow, I'm going to try it out now. I can't find the "CONTAINS" string function in the CFML reference. What category would it be under?

Comment: Under comparison operators - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html

Comment: For a *nix based system, you use `<cfif whereAmI.startswith("...")>` - or indeed you just use that version for both since it works (and fails faster).

Comment: Also, to prevent stuff like `bookings2` or whatever from incorrectly matching, the directory should end in a slash (and just use `getBaseTemplatePath()` without stripping the filename).

Comment: weird its not in the CFML reference but its in the developing applications guidebook.

Comment: @PeterBoughton where is the startswith() function in the CF documentation?

Comment: It's not CF, it's Java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29 - all CF strings are Java strings.

Comment: @volumeone - .. and because its java, be sure to check [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) for any nuances a) Unlike most CF functions it is case sensitive and b) `startsWith("")` always returns returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It is more easier with CGI variables. You can use "CF_TEMPLATE_PATH". Try this

```
<cfoutput>The value of CF_TEMPLATE_PATH is: </cfoutput><cfdump var="#CF_TEMPLATE_PATH#">
```